# Visualizing the mouse position in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I have the following code to move the mouse

```
 await page.mouse.move(500, 600);
```

But when it goes to the page, I don't see my cursor moving. Does Puppeteer hide the mouse cursor for some reason and I can't see it because of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puppeteer has no way to control the operating system's mouse -- it can only control the browser, which offers the ability to programmatically generate mouse events without actually moving the operating system's mouse, which, if you think about it, would be undesirable.

I assume by asking this question, your ultimate goal is to actually see the mouse position as controlled by Puppeteer. This doesn't appear to have been asked on Stack Overflow yet, but [Puppeteer issue #4378](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4378#issuecomment-499726973) has code ([`install-mouse-helper.js`](https://gist.github.com/aslushnikov/94108a4094532c7752135c42e12a00eb)) to render an HTML element on top of the mouse's logical location in the top-level frame for debugging purposes. This is done entirely in the browser, adding CSS and an element that updates on various mouse events. There's nothing Puppeteer-specific about it other than [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args) to ensure the code runs after navigation.